# What does "monkey in a tree" mean?

Tags: meaning

Forrest Gump speaks about his stay with Jenny:

> Forrest Gump: Every day we'd take a walk and I'd jabber on like a
> **monkey in a tree**, and she'd listen about Ping-Ponging, and shrimping, and Mama making a trip up to heaven. I did all the talking.

What does "monkey in a tree" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it is exactly what it says. Forrest is saying he was making as much noise as a monkey that is up in a tree when he was talking about "Ping-Ponging, and shrimping, and Mama making a trip up to heaven".

In other places "monkey" can imply people with low intelligence or low social graces ("They were acting like a bunch of monkeys") or it can imply children, especially cute children who are misbehaving or acting inappropriately ("You little monkeys, how dare you throw water on me.")  One has to be careful in using the word to refer to people since in the past it was used as a racial slur against black people.  But in the passage you cite, Forrest is using the word literally.